# Calculating the PRESS value in R

Tags: r

I have a linear regression and I wish to calculate the PRESS value for it in R, I can't seem to find any function or package that will allow me to do this, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: use package `qpcR` : http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/PRESS

Comment: @etienne Thanks but I seem to be unable to install the package,  "Warning in install.packages :package ‘qpcR ’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)" any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You might want to update your R version as the package was built for R 3.2.2

Comment: @etienne thanks, I'm just updating my r now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found those 3 solutions :

```
y<-rnorm(20)
x<-rnorm(20)

mod<-lm(y~x)

qpcR::PRESS(mod) 

.........10.........20
$stat
[1] 22.87275

$residuals
 [1]  1.55408878 -0.40260735  0.06609265 -0.17136355 -0.66509310 -0.05861872  2.17710614 -0.12711591
 [9] -0.98517163 -1.30087693 -0.03429331  0.77811943  1.34654198 -0.68948005 -0.47502687  1.05951306
[17]  1.36271586  0.01317017 -0.59414220 -2.43794103

$P.square
[1] -0.1417693

MPV::PRESS(mod) # just the stat
[1] 22.87275

DAAG::press(mod) # idem
[1] 22.87275
```

Hopefully one of these 3 will work for you

Comment: Thanks, all of these work for me!

Answer (score 2):

Try the pls package, I've had good results with it: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/